# about idekey and xdebug_session of xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

xdebug has two params: idekey and xdebug_session. I want to know what's the diff between those two?

It seems the two is the same.

Comment: You're a bit confusing saying "xdebug has two params", if you can eleborate a bit, then I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie is set accordingly to the setting of idekey. XDEBUG_SESSION doesn't exist when an debug session is not enabled, where as idekey should always be there.